# The command "find" cannot go on if the current folder is unmounted?

Tags: find, osx

I used a command on the Mac (with OS X Mavericks):

```
find /Volumes/Data -name '*hello*'
```

and it kept on giving an error.  I re-read the command line many times, and later found that the command line is not the issue. The issue is the current directory being `/Volumes/Docs` has been unmounted, probably due to inactivities.  Is this a bug? If I use `find` to find something from an absolute path, how come it cares about the current directory when it shouldn't matter? Is there a way to tell find not to care about it?

(and imagine if it is part of a shell script, and the shell script could fail because the person using the shell script is running in an existing shell where the current directory is unmounted. The shell script will fail due to this unexpected / unrelated reason).

Comment: the error `find: .: No such file or directory` indeeds says something about the current directory, but I was just too focused on why the usual command line wasn't working that I tried to fix the command line

Comment: Uh, you're operating in a directory that no longer exists. All sorts of stuff can fail if the current directory vanishes. No bug here.

Comment: but I am telling `find` to find something that is totally unrelated to the "current directory" which is part of the properties of a shell (Bash). So `find` should not be concerned about it